# User summary - default date span

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Click the mail icon next to your account name on the top of screen.

The default display is a summary of your recent activity. However, the time span's end date is later than the start date. (This might be timezone related.)

E.g. it's currently stating

```
2011-02-18 22:14:08Z to 2011-02-18 23:59:59Z
```

as the time span. (I'm GMT +11.)

*Also note that 'today' (the default display) is not in bold.*

Therefore, selecting the other menus (reputation, responses, favorites, revisions, and badges) all return nothing because of the incorrect timespan.

In practice, this can be rectified by clicking 'today'.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct.

The default is to show the activity since (approximately) the last time you checked. It has the end date of 11:59:59 **UTC** as that way the activity is always encompassed by the date range.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that. Sorry for the misunderstanding.